# How can I add my new .proto file and generate all necessary java files in gRPC's quick start template?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I wish to add my own .proto file from scratch in existing grpc-java quick start template. How can I generate all necessary class files and bind those with maven (or gradle) file.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven and Gradle protoc plugins build all protos in the `src/main/proto` directory (and `src/test/proto`, etc). So simply add your protos to the `examples/src/main/proto` directory and it will be generated as part of the normal build process.

Note that you can place the .proto files in subdirectories matching their package name. So if a proto has `package example`, it could be placed in `examples/src/main/proto/example/`.